# How to use scrollIntoView AFTER accordion expansion using React and React MUI

Tags: material-ui

Okay, is there any way to trigger a `el.scrollIntoView()` event without using a setTimeout? I feel this is a little bit of a hackish way in SPAs, as i've done it in Angular and React for this scenario, and am curious if anyone has a better solution.

I see that **when one container is already expanded, onReRendering it takes the new y-position of all elements, so when you click the next container it over scrolls**

Should I store my refs in a useMemo() to keep it's initial locations?

Currently I do this:

//useRef hook for building an array of ref items to anchor onto.

```
export const useMultipleRefs = () => {
  const refs = useRef<Record<string,HTMLElement | null>>({})

  const setRefFromKey = (key: string) => (element: HTMLElement | null) => {
    refs.current[key] = element;
  }

  return {refs: refs.current, setRefFromKey};
```

// Logic for the scrolling.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<string | false>(false);
const watchedSelections = useSelector(getWatchedSelections);
const [elRef, setClickedEl]=useState<{name:string, yPos:number}>({name:'', yPos:0});
const {refs, setRefFromKey} = useMultipleRefs();
const {height} = useViewPort();

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    document.getElementById(elRef.name)?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start"}) 
  }, 400); 
}, [elRef])

const handleChange = (panel: string) => (event: React.SyntheticEvent, isExpanded: boolean) => {
  setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
};

const detectChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
  console.log(event);
}

const setNewRefElement= (tagRef:string, yPos:number) => {
  setClickedEl({name: tagRef, yPos: yPos});
}
```

And my JSX looks like this:

```
       return (
          <Accordion
            key={selection.tag}
            ref={setRefFromKey(selection.tag)}
            id={selection.tag}
            // className={expanded ? 'add-scroll-margin' : ''}
            TransitionProps={{ unmountOnExit: false }} 
            expanded={expanded === `${selection.tag}`} 
            onClick={(e)=>{ setNewRefElement(selection.tag, e.clientY ) }}
            onChange={handleChange(selection.tag)}>
          <AccordionSummary
            aria-controls={`${selection.tag}-content`}
            id={`${selection.tag}-header`}
            className='scroll-ref'
            sx={selectionSummaryStyling}
          >
            <SelectionsListItem selection={selection} />
          </AccordionSummary>
          
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>
              //...content with 380px height here.
            </Typography>
          </AccordionDetails>

          </Accordion>
        )
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a useful example:

```
const MyAccordion = (props) => {
  const scrollToRef = useRef([])
  

  const executeScroll = (i) => {
    scrollToRef?.current?.[i]?.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest',
    })
  }

  return (
    <Collapse
      ...
      onChange={(i) => {
        window.setTimeout(() => executeScroll(i), 500)
      }}
    >
      {data.map((item, id) => (
        <Panel header={item.header} key={id}>
          <div
            ref={(el) => {
              if (el) {
                scrollToRef.current[id] = el
              }
            }}
          >
            ...
          </div>
        </Panel>
      ))}
    </Collapse>
  )
}
```

Comment: will play around with this again, and get back to you. Thanks Nagibaba!

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using MUI5, as far as I can tell, any callback passed to the onEntered and onExited props will fire when the component finishes expanding or collapsing respectively. So you should be able to pass a handler to those and then trigger the scrolling within that handler without having to resort to using setTimeout anywhere. That's been working well for me.